# Kosaraju implementation in C not completely correct

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, kosaraju-algorithm, kosaraju-sharir

I am trying to implement Kosaraju's algorithm that finds strongly connected components in a directed graph in a linear time but the result is not correct and my implementation probably has a small error. I need help.

What my outputs:

```
Strongly Connected Component #1: 1,2,
```

What it should output:

```
Strongly Connected Component #1: 8,
Strongly Connected Component #2: 3,7,6,5,4,
Strongly Connected Component #3: 1,2,
Strongly Connected Component #4: 0,
```

Implementation:

```
/**
 * Kosaraju's algorithm implementation which is a linear time algorithm
 * to find the strongly connected components of a directed graph.
 * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/kosaraju's_algorithm
 */

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct vertex {
    int value;
    struct vertex *next;
};

typedef struct vertex Vertex;

typedef struct graph {
    int num_vertices;
    Vertex **neighbors;
};

typedef struct graph Graph;

struct stack {
    int value;
    struct stack *next;
};

typedef struct stack Stack;

/**
 * @brief Create stack using endogenous linked list
 * @param stack pointer to a stack pointer
 */
static void stack_create(Stack **stack) {
    *stack = NULL;
}

/**
 * @brief Push method of stack
 * @param stack pointer to a stack pointer
 * @param value value to push to stack
 */
static void stack_push(Stack **stack, int value) {
    Stack *item = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    item->value = value;
    item->next = *stack;
    *stack = item;
}

/**
 * @brief Pop method of stack
 * @param stack pointer to a stack pointer
 */
static bool stack_pop(Stack **stack) {
    Stack *old = *stack;
    if (!old)
        return false;

    *stack = old->next;
    free(old);
    return true;
}

/**
 * @brief Checks whether stack is empty or not
 * @param stack pointer to a stack pointer
 * @return boolean indicating whether stack is empty or not
 */
static bool stack_is_empty(Stack **stack) {
    return *stack == NULL;
}

/**
 * @brief Create graph given number of vertices implemented using adjacency
 * @return pointer to allocated graph
 */
static Graph *graph_create(int num_vertices) {
    Graph *graph = malloc(sizeof(Graph));
    graph->num_vertices = num_vertices;
    size_t vertices_size = num_vertices * sizeof(Vertex *);
    graph->neighbors = (Vertex **) malloc(vertices_size);
    memset(graph->neighbors, NULL, vertices_size);
    return graph;
}

/**
 * @brief Add edge method of graph
 * @param graph pointer to graph
 * @param source index of source
 * @param sink index of sink
 */
static void graph_add_edge(Graph *graph, int source, int sink) {
    Vertex *item = (Vertex *) malloc(sizeof(Vertex));
    item->value = sink;
    item->next = graph->neighbors[source];
    graph->neighbors[source] = item;
}

/**
 * @brief DFS traversal of graph
 * @param graph pointer to graph
 * @param stack pointer to stack
 * @param visited visited boolean array
 * @param v vertex
 */
static void dfs(Graph *graph, Stack **stack, bool *visited, int v) {
    visited[v] = true;
    Vertex *neighbors = graph->neighbors[v];
    while (neighbors != NULL) {
        if (!visited[neighbors->value]) {
            dfs(graph, stack, visited, neighbors->value);
        }
        neighbors = neighbors->next;
    }
    stack_push(stack, v);
}

/**
 * @brief Builds reverse of graph
 * @param graph pointer to graph
 * @return reversed graph
 */
static Graph *reverse(Graph *graph) {
    Graph *reversed_graph = graph_create(graph->num_vertices);

    int i;
    Vertex *neighbors;
    for (i = 0; i < graph->num_vertices; i++) {
        neighbors = graph->neighbors[i];
        while (neighbors != NULL) {
            graph_add_edge(reversed_graph, neighbors->value, i);
            neighbors = neighbors->next;
        }
    }
    return reversed_graph;
}

/**
 * @brief Use dfs to list a set of vertices dfs_and_print from a vertex v in H
 * @param graph pointer to graph
 * @param visited boolean array indicating whether index has been visited or not
 * @param deleted boolean array indicating whether index has been popped or not
 * @param v vertex
 */
void dfs_and_print(Graph *graph, bool *visited, bool *deleted, int v) {
    printf("%d,", v);
    visited[v] = true;
    deleted[v] = true;
    Vertex *arcs = graph->neighbors[v];  // the adjacent list of vertex v
    while (arcs != NULL) {
        int u = arcs->value;
        if (!visited[u] && !deleted[u]) {
            dfs_and_print(graph, visited, deleted, u);
        }
        arcs = arcs->next;
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Collect SCC from the graph
 * @param graph pointer to graph
 * @param stack pointer to a stack pointer
 * @param visited boolean array indicating whether index has been visited or not
 */
void collect_scc(Graph *graph, Stack **stack, bool *visited) {
    bool *deleted = (bool *) alloca(graph->num_vertices * sizeof(bool));
    memset(deleted, false, graph->num_vertices * sizeof(bool));
    int c = 1;
    while (!stack_is_empty(stack)) {
        int v = stack_pop(stack);
        if (!deleted[v]) {
            memset(visited, false,
                   graph->num_vertices *
                   sizeof(bool));  // mark all vertices of reverse as not visited
            printf("Strongly Connected Component #%d: ", c);
            dfs_and_print(graph, visited, deleted, v);
            printf("\n");
            c++;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Kosaraju logic
 * @param graph pointer to graph
 */
static void kosaraju(Graph *graph) {
    Stack *stack;
    stack_create(&stack);

    size_t visited_size = graph->num_vertices * sizeof(bool);
    bool *visited = (bool *) alloca(visited_size);
    memset(visited, false, visited_size);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < graph->num_vertices; i++) {
        if (!visited[i]) {
            dfs(graph, &stack, visited, i);
        }
    }

    Graph *reversed_graph = reverse(graph);
    collect_scc(reversed_graph, &stack, visited);
}

int main() {
    Graph *graph = graph_create(10);
    graph_add_edge(graph, 1, 2);
    graph_add_edge(graph, 2, 1);

    graph_add_edge(graph, 3, 4);
    graph_add_edge(graph, 4, 5);
    graph_add_edge(graph, 5, 6);
    graph_add_edge(graph, 6, 7);
    graph_add_edge(graph, 7, 3);

    kosaraju(graph);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @kaylum yes. I found the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my `stack_pop` method was returning a boolean indicating if poping from the stack was successful or not but in `collect_scc` I was using the returned value (i.e. `boolean`) as the value that has just been popped from the stack.

```
static bool stack_pop(Stack **stack, int* v) {
    Stack *old = *stack;
    if (!old)
        return false;

    *v = old->value;
    *stack = old->next;
    free(old);
    return true;
}
```